# How can i remove duplicate files in google drive using app script with javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, duplicates

I want to identify duplicate files in Google drive and delete them. please guide or correct mycode.

```
while (folder.hasNext()) {
        var folders = folder.next();
        var Getfiles = folders.getFilesByName(file.getName());
        Logger.log("Folder Name: " + folders.getName());
        while (Getfiles.hasNext()) {
          var Getfile = Getfiles.next();
          if(Getfile.getFilesByName(Getfile.getName()) >1)
          //I don't know what to do here
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

My question for you would be how do you define a file as duplicate you appear to be just checking if the name is the same.  What about files in different directories, files of different sizes, or if they have different dates. Which one do you want to keep?

If I was doing this I would check file name, location and date to ensure that I have the newest file.

I would run a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) and get a list of every file on my Google drive account.   Then i would sort the files locally by directory then by name and date.    Once the files are sorted i would run though them if there was more then one file i would send a [file.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/delete) to Google for each of the duplicate files.  The issue here is that you are going to have to do all the comparing locally.

Technically speaking you could also do a  [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) then loop though each file and make another  [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) request to google asking with the [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) parameter looking for other files of the same name.   Check what is returned to and delete any of the returned files that are in the same directory as the file we are checking and have a younger date.   This solution is going to eat more of your quota as you are making more requests to Google.

Comment: I am using Javascript, sorry for that.

Comment: I cant help much with JavaScript code you might want to try option two as depending upon how much data is in your drive account option one might be a bit heavy.

Comment: Or is there a way I can prevent this code var file = folder.createFile(attachment); from processing already processes attachments? because my duplicates occurs when the script runs and fetches attachments from Gmail to Gdrive.

Comment: Create file doesnt check if the file exists thats your job check first then create it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code, I hope it can help some of you guys who may need something similar.

```
 for (var msgIdx=0; msgIdx<messages.length; msgIdx++) {
        var message = messages[msgIdx];
        Logger.log("INFO:       Processing message: "+message.getSubject() + " (" + message.getId() + ")");
        var messageDate = message.getDate();
        var attachments = message.getAttachments();
        for (var attIdx=0; attIdx<attachments.length; attIdx++) {
          var attachment = attachments[attIdx];
          Logger.log("INFO:         Processing attachment: "+attachment.getName());
          try {
            var folder = getOrCreateFolder(rule.folder);
            var getFoldersByName = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(rule.folder);
             var newFilename = Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, config.timezone, rule.filenameTo.replace('%s',message.getSubject()));
             while (getFoldersByName.hasNext()) {
              var FetchhedFolders = getFoldersByName.next();
              var GetFiles = FetchhedFolders.getFiles();
              while (GetFiles.hasNext()) {
                var files = GetFiles.next();
                var GetFileName = FetchhedFolders.getFilesByName(newFilename);
                if(GetFileName.hasNext() )
                {
                  FetchhedFolders.removeFile(newFilename);
                }else if (!GetFileName.hasNext())
                {
                 var file = folder.createFile(attachment);                               
                 if (rule.filenameFrom && rule.filenameTo && rule.filenameFrom == file.getName()) {
                  Logger.log("INFO:           Renaming matched file '" + file.getName() + "' -> '" + newFilename + "'");
                  file.setName(newFilename);
                }
                else if (rule.filenameTo) {
                  var newFilename = Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, config.timezone, rule.filenameTo.replace('%s',message.getSubject()));
                  Logger.log("INFO:           Renaming '" + file.getName() + "' -> '" + newFilename + "'");
                  file.setName(newFilename);
                }
                file.setDescription("Mail title: " + message.getSubject() + "\nMail date: " + message.getDate() + "\nMail link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/" + message.getId());
                Utilities.sleep(config.sleepTime);
                }
              }
            }

          } catch (e) {
            Logger.log(e);
          }
        }
      }
```